# How to see how long a JButton is held down for using a MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have a simple class:

```java
public class MyButton extends JToggleButton {
    public MyButton() {
        super();
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                // See if it has been pressed for two seconds here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to simply print `"Hello World!"` after the user has pressed and held for two seconds.

Comment: please add what your code sample of what have done so far.

Comment: Why not just start a timer when receiving the `mousePressed()` event and stopping the timer on the `mouseReleased()` event?

Comment: @maloomeister Because i want the user to keep holding the button and for the message to be printed and then they release

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JButton long press event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872483/jbutton-long-press-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) that starts on `mousePressed` and will fire after X seconds, but stops `onMouseReleased`.

Consider this class:

```
public class ClickHoldMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private Timer fireTimer;
        private MouseEvent lastEvent;

        public ClickHoldMouseListener(int holdTime, Consumer<MouseEvent> eventConsumer) {
            fireTimer = new Timer(holdTime, e -> eventConsumer.accept(lastEvent));
            fireTimer.setRepeats(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            lastEvent = e;
            fireTimer.restart();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            fireTimer.stop();
        }
    }
```

Now, you can add it to your button:

```
JButton button = new JButton("button");
button.addMouseListener(new ClickHoldMouseListener(2000, (event) -> {
    System.out.println("Mouse click was hold for 2seconds.");
}));
```

Note that the injected event is the mouse event from `mousePressed` method. You can change the consumer to  a `Runnable` in order to ignore the event, or a `Consumer<ActionEvent>` to catch the event of the timer.